# How to turn an ArrayList with Object[]'s into an Object[][] array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` with `Object[]`'s and I need to convert the `ArrayList` into an `Object[][]` array in order to put the data in a `JTable`. How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
(Object[][]) arraylist.toArray();
```

but that gave:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `toArray`, like this:

```
Object[][] array2d = (Object[][])arraylist.toArray(new Object[arraylist.size()][]);
```

This is a non-generic version; generic `toArray(T[] a)` lets you avoid the cast.

Comment: That gives an `Object[]` instead of an `Object[][]` according to Netbeans

Comment: @com.BOY It looks like you've got a non-generic list then - you need to add a cast.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, an explicit solution that takes into account arrays with variable lengths:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> input = new ArrayList<>();
Object[][] output = new Object[input.size()][];

for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    Object[] array = input.get(i);
    output[i] = new Object[array.length];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, output[i], 0, array.length);
}
```

Comment: Instead of the second `for` loop, you can use `System.arraycopy(array, 0, output[i], 0, array.length);`

Comment: @BackSlash yes, that's nicer. Edited!

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Object[]{1,2,3});

    Object[][] objArray = new Object[list.size()][];
    for (int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
        objArray[i] = list.get(i).clone();
```